# Multiline tooltips and CMFCButton

Tags: button, mfc, tooltip

At the moment I am using a standard [`CButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class?view=msvc-160) control and my own derived `CMultilineToolTipCtrl` to be able to display multiline tool tips.

I thought I would try out the [`CMFCButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class?view=msvc-160) control as an alternative because it has native support for a tooltip by calling [`SetTooltip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class?view=msvc-160#settooltip).

However, it does not seem to support multiline text from what I can tell. Is there a simple solution to this or should I stick with what I have coded?

Comment: IIRC, and I don't have my old code from my old job on hand... but, if you set the width of the tooltip, I believe it will wrap text or at least allow you to put line feeds in it. Maybe look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/implement-multiline-tooltips

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Thanks. I did try using `\r\n` and it just stripped off the second line of text. I think I will just stick with what I have for now.

Comment: Did you try setting the width of the tooltip? IIRC, that was part of the formula for getting it to work. CRLFs were not enough on their own.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Actually, that tis basically what the multiline tool tip control that I derived does. It sets the tip width. So I will just stick with that. It is a pity that the MFC controls that sponsor a tooltip did not correctly support multiline text without any manual calculating of the tip width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the derived tooltip control that determines the correct width for the tool tip control:

```
UINT CMultilineToolTipCtrl::FitText(CString &rStrText)
{
    CClientDC       *pDC ;
    CFont           *pFntTip, *pFntOld ;
    CRect           rctMargin, rctTip ;
    CSize           sizText ;
    CString         strTextCopy, strLine, strChaff ;
    CStringArray    aryStrLines ;
    UINT            uMaxWidth;
    INT_PTR         uNumLines, uLineIndex ;

    uMaxWidth = 0 ; // Fallback.

    GetMargin(&rctMargin);
    GetClientRect(&rctTip);

    // Reduce by the given margins to get the true area.
    rctTip.left += rctMargin.left ;
    rctTip.top += rctMargin.top ;
    rctTip.right -= rctMargin.right ;
    rctTip.bottom -= rctMargin.bottom ;

    pDC = new CClientDC(this);
    if (pDC != nullptr)
    {
        pFntTip = GetFont();
        pFntOld = (CFont *)pDC->SelectObject(pFntTip);

        // First, find the longest line.
        strTextCopy = rStrText ;
        uMaxWidth = 0 ;
        while (strTextCopy != _T("") )
        {
            strLine = strTextCopy.SpanExcluding(_T("\r\n") );
            strTextCopy.Delete(0, strLine.GetLength() );
            strChaff = strTextCopy.SpanIncluding(_T("\r\n") );
            strTextCopy.Delete(0, strChaff.GetLength() );

            sizText = pDC->GetTextExtent(strLine);
            if (sizText.cx > (int)uMaxWidth)
                uMaxWidth = sizText.cx ;
            aryStrLines.Add(strLine);
        }

        rStrText = _T("");
        uNumLines = aryStrLines.GetSize();

        // Now, pad all lines to that max width.
        for (uLineIndex = 0 ; uLineIndex < uNumLines ; uLineIndex++)
        {
            strLine = aryStrLines.GetAt(uLineIndex);
            sizText = pDC->GetTextExtent(strLine);
            while (sizText.cx <= (int)uMaxWidth)
            {
                strLine += _T(" ");
                sizText = pDC->GetTextExtent(strLine);
            }

            rStrText += strLine ;
        }

        SendMessage(TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH, 0, uMaxWidth);

        pDC->SelectObject(pFntOld);

        delete pDC ;
    }

    return uMaxWidth ;
}
```

If you have a simpler way to calculate the width then I welcome your answers.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have a simpler way to calculate the width then I welcome your answers.

```cpp
void CMyMFCButton::UpdateTooltipText(const std::vector<CString>& listText)
{
    const auto pDC = m_pToolTip->GetDC();
    LONG nMaxWidth{};

    if (listText.empty())
    {
        SetTooltip(nullptr);
        return;
    }

    CString strTooltip;
    for (const auto& strText : listText)
    {
        if (!strTooltip.IsEmpty())
        {
            strTooltip += L"\r\n";
        }

        if (pDC != nullptr)
        {
            const auto nWidth = pDC->GetTextExtent(strText).cx;
            nMaxWidth = max(nWidth, nMaxWidth);
        }

        strTooltip += strText;
    }
    SetTooltip(strTooltip);

    if (nMaxWidth > 0)
    {
        m_pToolTip->SendMessage(TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH, 0, nMaxWidth);
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine with a derived class of `CMFCButton`.